# How to write regex to match an string, based on some conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text string like this:

```
SOMEVALUE=TEST;SOME_VALUE_2=VALUE;SOME_VALUE_3=TESTValue
```

for this string I need to find the value of `SOME_VALUE_2`, which is in this case `VALUE`, but it can be any (ex `NEWVALUE` etc)

I tried this regex:

```
SOME_VALUE_2=.*[;]
```

but this matches the complete text:

```
SOME_VALUE_2=VALUE;
```

but I want to match only `VALUE` and return.

How would I do that?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: Running on javascript

Comment: You should put the part you dont need in non-capturing group. e.g. `(?=SOME_VALUE_2=).+?(?=;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
SOME_VALUE_2=(.*);SOME_VALUE_3
```

What you'll be looking for will be in capture group 1.

Tested @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rH3hQ6/5)

If you don't want to use capture groups, then you can try this lookahead/lookbehind pattern

```
(?<=SOME_VALUE_2=).*(?=;SOME_VALUE_3)
```

Tested @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rH3hQ6/6)

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this pattern:

```
SOME_VALUE_2=([^;]+)
```

Here before and till `=` sign you can specify any key and then you can capture anything which is not `;`.

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/NPdoGsEcXR)

Comment: @torazaburo, it was redundant.